# How to groupby a pandas dataframe column and save different group to multiple sheets in same excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dataframe. I need to save same group of data in different sheets on same excel file

I have following dataset

```
District    Prefix  Quota       
A           98426   783
A           98427   223
A           98446   127
A           98626   51
B           98049   167
B           98079   153
B           98140   120
B           98159   139
B           98169   182
B           98249   86
B           98426   588
B           98446   96
C           98049   104
C           98060   68
C           98149   65
C           98150   68
C           98159   86
C           98160   80
C           98169   113
```

Code to reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A', 98426, 783],
    ['A', 98427, 223],
    ['A', 98446, 127],
    ['A', 98626, 51],
    ['B', 98049, 167],
    ['B', 98079, 153],
    ['B', 98140, 120],
    ['B', 98159, 139],
    ['B', 98169, 182],
    ['B', 98249, 86],
    ['B', 98426, 588],
    ['B', 98446, 96],
    ['C', 98049, 104],
    ['C', 98060, 68],
    ['C', 98149, 65],
    ['C', 98150, 68],
    ['C', 98159, 86],
    ['C', 98160, 80],
    ['C', 98169, 113]
], 
    columns=['District', 'Prefix', 'Quota'])
```

so you can see in "District" column there is A, B and C data . now I have to create a excel file called "District_Data" and save datas of A in separate sheet named "A" and B in separate sheet named "B" and so on. but all the sheets should be in "District_Data" excel file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
uniques = df.District.unique()

with pd.ExcelWriter('District_Data.xlsx') as writer:
    for District in uniques:
        df[df.District == District].to_excel(writer, index=None, sheet_name=District)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can group data by District.

If you have only one index column:

```py
data = df.groupby('District')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('District_data.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for row,group in data:
    group.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=row)
writer.save()
```

for the MultiIndex scenario replace for loop with:

```py
for row, group in data.groupby(level=0):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your dataframe and then save to excel specifying the sheet name you want to use, something like this:

```
for district in ['A','B','C']:
    # filter on district
    df_filter = df.loc[df.District==district]
    # save to District_data.xlsx, sheet = district
    df_filter.to_excel("District_data.xlsx",sheet_name = district)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll coontinue the theme of so many answers similar but slightly different:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('District_Data.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for i in df['District'].drop_duplicates().to_list():
    df.loc[df['District'] == i].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=i)
writer.save()
```